# [PL/SQL]: Declare "partition_name" Error

Tags: plsql

I'm getting the error to declare `partition_name` found in C3 being `"PLS-00302: component 'PARTITION_NAME' must be declared"`. The purpose of this code is to automate resizing of tables and indexes. Please ignore the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` as it's only there to identify whether the loops and if statements operate as intended. Any possible solutions will be greatly appreciated.

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR C1 IS 
     select MAX(block_id)AS block_id, file_id -- Is Not Free
     from   sys.dba_extents
     where  tablespace_name = 'USERS'
     GROUP BY file_id;
    CURSOR C2 IS 
     select MAX(block_id)AS block_id, file_id --Is Free
     from   sys.dba_free_space
     where  tablespace_name = 'USERS'
     GROUP BY file_id;
    Cursor C3  IS                --(globvar  VARCHAR2(255 CHAR))
     SELECT owner, segment_name, partition_name
     from   sys.dba_extents
     where  tablespace_name= 'USERS' AND block_id=(SELECT MAX(block_id)FROM sys.dba_extents WHERE tablespace_name='USERS');
    Cursor C4 (objname VARCHAR2) IS
     SELECT object_type
     FROM dba_objects
     WHERE object_name = objname;


--These are the variables used to retrieve data from the cursors. 
IsNotFree C1%ROWTYPE;--sys.dba_extents.block_id%TYPE; 
IsNotFreeName C3%ROWTYPE;
IsFree C2%ROWTYPE;
IsFreeBlockNo sys.dba_free_space.blocks%TYPE;
ObjectType VARCHAR2(10 CHAR);


BEGIN
    OPEN C1;
    OPEN C2;
    OPEN C3;
    --FOR IsNotFreeName IN c1;
    --for IsFree IN c2;
    FETCH C3 INTO IsNotFreeName;
    OPEN C4 (IsNotFreeName.segment_name); 
    FETCH C4 INTO ObjectType;
      --Loop The file Ids
    FOR IsNotFreeName IN C1
    LOOP
    IF C1%FOUND AND C2%FOUND THEN  -- fetch succeeded
        FOR IsFree IN C2
            LOOP
                IF C1%FOUND AND C2%FOUND THEN  -- fetch succeeded
                IF  IsNotFree.block_id > IsFree.block_id AND IsFree.file_id=IsNotFree.file_id THEN
                    IF ObjectType = 'TABLE' THEN
                        IF IsNotFreeName.partition_name = NULL THEN--The Error 
                            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('alter table '|| IsNotFreeName.owner||'.'||IsNotFreeName.segment_name||' move');
                        ELSE
                            dbms_output.put_line('alter table '||IsNotFreeName.owner ||'.'||IsNotFreeName.segment_name||' move partition ' || IsNotFreeName.partition_name);
                        END IF;
                    ELSIF ObjectType = 'INDEX' THEN
                        IF IsNotFreeName.partition_name = NULL THEN
                            dbms_output.put_line('alter index '||IsNotFreeName.owner||'.'||IsNotFreeName.segment_name||' rebuild');
                        ELSE
                            dbms_output.put_line ('alter index'|| IsNotFreeName.owner||'.'||IsNotFreeName.segment_name||' rebuild partition'|| IsNotFreeName.partition_name);
                        END IF;
                   ELSE
                        dbms_output.put_line ('ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE [path] RESIZE '||TRUNC(IsFreeBlockNo/128)||'M');
    --ELSE  -- fetch failed
       -- EXIT;
                  END IF;
              END IF;
              END IF;
            END LOOP;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different `isnotfreename` records. The first is declared as `c3%rowtype` (owner, segment_name, partition_name), the second implicitly as part of `for isnotfreename in c1 loop` (block_id, file_id). The second one is in scope within the `for` loop, and that's why the reference to `partition_name` is invalid.

Your next problem will probably be that you attempt to open `c1` twice, so the second one (the `for` loop again) will fail with a 'cursor already open' error.

(That's before you get to the '`= null`' problem Raj Te has already spotted.)

I advise never using generic numbered names for variables, as it is just needlessly confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty self confusing code here. The error is valid. Also many places curosrs are not closed. Apart you are checking something equals to NULL. It should have done via "IS NULL". Check below how:

```
FOR IsNotFreeName IN C1  -- *You are running this loop. Now you cursor C1 has not partition_name. Thats why its throwing the error.* 
    LOOP
    IF C1%FOUND AND C2%FOUND THEN  
        FOR IsFree IN C2
            LOOP
                IF C1%FOUND AND C2%FOUND THEN  
                IF  IsNotFree.block_id > IsFree.block_id AND IsFree.file_id=IsNotFree.file_id THEN
                    IF ObjectType = 'TABLE' THEN
                        IF IsNotFreeName.partition_name = NULL THEN--The valid Error. Apart you must use `IsNotFreeName.partition_name is NULL`
                            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('alter table '|| IsNotFreeName.owner||'.'||IsNotFreeName.segment_name||' move');
                        ELSE
```